# Debugging Shopware 6 Twig files in PhpStorm

Tags: twig, phpstorm, xdebug, shopware

I am new to Shopware 6 and have installed it with Docker and locally. I use PhpStorm and thought I could [debug the twig files](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/symfony-twig.html#debugging-twig-templates) but I have not been able to get this to work for me. I have been trying to debug my plugin. I haven't been able to find any similar questions or the answer so far.

When I check for debug environments

```
debug: true 
auto_reload: true
```

I think I can only see them in the Test directories, but then does this mean that I would I need to set this up for my plugin directory? I also don't know how to locate the [Twig compiled templates cache](https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2019/05/twig-and-blade-templates-debugging-2/).

How are you debugging the Twig files and do you have a special set up?
I am sorry for not being clear, as I don't know what the problem is, other than my debugging of Twig does not work.

Thanks in advance for any hints of pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: What component are you trying to debug? A test or a plugin? 1) Environments options are described starting here: https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/api.html#basics, this should give you the basic idea of setting the up 2) this section also describes how to find & define "twig compiled templates cache" directory. Just make sure to read through it carefully, find your cache folder, run the site to generate caches, check they're created in a file system & then adjust IDE settings accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, @Dmitrii I edited the question to include that I was trying to debug my plugin. I will check the documentation again, as I probably missed something,